# Defining a 'Watch' class

Tags: objective-c, datetime

This is the first program (that is not doing much basically), and I know usually you define classes in separate files.  I just wanted to see if I got the syntax right, and the concept of using objects from the first chapter of the book.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

//interface section
@interface Watch: NSObject

-(void) setHours: (int) h;
-(void) setMinutes: (int) m;
-(int) getHours;
-(int) getMinutes;
-(void) printTime;

@end

//implemetation section

@implementation Watch 

{
    int hours;
    int minuts;
}

- (void) setHours: (int) h
{
    hours = h;
}

- (void) setMinutes:(int) m
{
    minuts = m;
}

- (int) getHours
{
    return hours;
}

- (int) getMinutes
{
    return minuts;
}

-(void) printTime
{
    NSLog(@"Time is %i:%i", hours, minuts);
}

@end

//the program section 

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool
    {

        Watch *myWatch = [[Watch alloc]init];

        [myWatch getHours];

        [myWatch getMinutes];

        [myWatch setHours: 5];

        [myWatch setMinutes: 30];

        [myWatch printTime];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely check out how [properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW5) can make your code shorter, by adding some standard setter/getter

```
@interface Watch: NSObject

@property int hours;
@property int minutes;
-(void) printTime;

@end


@implementation Watch 

-(void) printTime
{
    NSLog(@"Time is %i:%i", _hours, _minutes);
}

@end
```

Also the naming convention of a getter is the property name

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool
    {
        Watch *myWatch = [[Watch alloc]init];
        [myWatch setHours: 5];
        [myWatch setMinutes: 30];

        int hours = [myWatch hours]; //standard getter
        int minutes = [myWatch minutes];
        [myWatch printTime];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[naming conventions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH10-SW1) are important in Cocoa, as higher level technologies as Key-Value-Observing depends on them.